# Matplotlib get_ylim() changing data transformation result

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

"get_ylim()" is changing the result of the transformation from data to display coordinates in matplotlib (I'm using version 3.2.1). Is it supposed to change axis properties? It's the same effect using "get_xlim()".
Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dpi = 80
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1280/dpi, 720/dpi), dpi=dpi)

x = np.arange(200)
y = - 0.1 * x
ax.plot(x, y)

points = ax.transData.transform(np.vstack((x, y)).T).astype(int)
print(points[:5])

ax.get_ylim()

points = ax.transData.transform(np.vstack((x, y)).T).astype(int)
print(points[:5])
```

Both prints output different results only with the ax.get_ylim() in place.